# Enable/Disable the recommended jobs in the feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app

The recommended jobs are great. But most people most of the times are not looking for a job. So most times that part is just noise.

It would be useful if that part of the feed could be disabled through the settings page

Comment: I would appreciate the same thing on the iOS app.